# NetSuite & PHP: Search SelectCustomFieldRef Custom Field

Tags: php, netsuite

I have a script that needs to get fulfillment data from netsuite and have a code

$myWebService =  app('NetSuiteWebService');
        $myWebService->setSearchPreferences(false, 10);

```
    $search = new TransactionSearchBasic();

    // Record that is sales order type
    $so = new RecordRef();
    $so->type = 'salesOrder';

    // get the order item fulfillment
    $type = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField();
    $type->searchValue = '_itemFulfillment';
    $type->operator = 'anyOf';
    $search->type= $type;

    // custom field filter to get only custom field custbody_do_no_send_macship to FALSE
    $searchBooleanCustomFieldList = new SearchColumnBooleanCustomField();
    $searchBooleanCustomFieldList->searchValue = false;
    $searchBooleanCustomFieldList->scriptId = 'custbody_do_not_send_machship';

    // custom field filter to get only tracking that is not empty
    $searchStringCustomField =  new SearchStringCustomField();
    $searchStringCustomField->operator = 'notEmpty';
    $searchStringCustomField->scriptId = 'custbody13';

    // TODO: NOT CORRECT custom field filter to get only the shipping group that does not have pickup
    $searchMultiSelectCustomField = new SearchMultiSelectCustomField();
    $searchMultiSelectCustomField->scriptId = 'custbody12';
    $searchMultiSelectCustomField->operator = 'doesNotContain';
    $searchMultiSelectCustomField->searchValue = 'Pick Up';


    // set all custom field as an array to get from the search
    $searchColumnCustomFieldList = new SearchColumnCustomFieldList();
    $searchColumnCustomFieldList->customField = array(
        $searchBooleanCustomFieldList,
        $searchStringCustomField,
        $searchMultiSelectCustomField);

    // filter for the last 12 hours
    $searchDateField = new SearchDateField();
    $searchDateField->operator = "after";
    $searchDateField->searchValue = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000\Z', strtotime('-12 hour'));
    $search->dateCreated = $searchDateField;

    $request = new SearchRequest();
    $request->searchRecord = $search;
    $response = $myWebService->search($request);
```

So far every query has given me the correct results except for this one

```
// TODO: NOT CORRECT custom field filter to get only the shipping group that does not have pickup
        $searchMultiSelectCustomField = new SearchMultiSelectCustomField();
        $searchMultiSelectCustomField->scriptId = 'custbody12';
        $searchMultiSelectCustomField->operator = 'doesNotContain';
        $searchMultiSelectCustomField->searchValue = 'Pick Up';
```

The issue is the custom field is a SelectCustomFieldRef with a value that is a ListOrRecordRef which has a value of

```
+customField: array:8 [▼
      0 => SelectCustomFieldRef {#410 ▼
        +value: ListOrRecordRef {#411 ▼
          +name: "Pick Up Bundaberg"
          +internalId: "10"
          +externalId: null
          +typeId: "199"
        }
        +internalId: "1551"
        +scriptId: "custbody12"
      }
```

I need to remove orders that has name with the word "Pick Up" in this custom field but when I run this it still contains fulfillments that have a "Pick Up" in the name ? What is the correct query ?

Answer (score 0):

Value for your search multi select should be an array of internal ids from your list.

Comment: I don't know the internal ids so I'm basing my query on what the data I can get and the parameters that was given to me, that is why I'm asking this.

Comment: Not knowing the internal IDs is a big problem. You need the IDs.